# How do I invoke a Amazon SageMaker endpoint with the Python SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to use this very simple command:

`import boto3
client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')`

listed in the [documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sagemaker-runtime.html#SageMakerRuntime.Client.invoke_endpoint)

but i'm getting this error:

`UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'sagemaker-runtime'. Valid service names are: acm, etc..`

My goal is to be able to invoke the endpoint that I've created in Amazon SageMaker.

I'm doing this from a Jupyter notebook in Sagemaker, so I feel like this should work no problem. How do I get it to run here, and outside of the Sagemaker environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon SageMaker is a very new service (December 2017).

You will need to update your boto library to use it:

```
sudo pip install boto --upgrade
sudo pip install boto3 --upgrade
sudo pip install awscli --upgrade
```

Comment: I'd recommend pip install --upgrade botocore as well

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is incorrect. This is how you get the client with the SageMaker Python SDK.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
```

I've done this successfully. And, as John said, be sure to update your versions of `boto3` and `awscli`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use Jupyter Notebook, create cell at the top and execute below.

```
!pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

In my case, to upgrade boto3 in terminal didn't work.